# Trying to access a required files array in a PHP Class constructor

Tags: php, class, require-once

I am making a really silly error that I have no idea why.

I include a file right before a class declaration like this :

```
require_once('assets.php') //php_include_path is set to the correct folder and the file loads
class A{


function __construct(){
var_dump($assets); // dumps NULL
}
}
```

In assets.php, I have an array like this:

```
$assets['file'] = array('abc','qrd');
```

So why am I getting NULL here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and)

Comment: thats because of scope and in addition u should get undefined variable $assets as notice if the error reporting is on for notice.

Comment: Why not `return` the array to a variable in the local script and pass it into the constructor of the class `__construct($assets)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods I would choose for this, depending on on your situation, you can decide what works best.

Use assets as an argument to the class constructor.  $assets will only be available in the constructor unless you use a class property like below.

```
require_once('assets.php');
class A{
  function __construct($assets){
    var_dump($assets);
  }
}
$a = new A($assets);
```

or

Put the require in the constructor.  This example also features a class property so you can use `$this->_assets` in all of the class's methods.

```
class A{
  protected $_assets;
  function __construct(){
    require_once('assets.php');
    $this->_assets = $assets;
    var_dump($this->_assets);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Devon. Both solutions seem good. Out of curiosity, I have multiple class files with a require_once statement. right before the Class is declared. These require_once files have Classes within them, so in the constructors of the including files class, I am able to create objects of the require_once file's class without having to do any of the aforementioned techniques. But somehow this does not work for arrays, how is that possible ?

Comment: Can you update your original post with an example?  It might be easier for me to wrap my head around what you're asking if I see it more visually.